# V$SQL table elapsed time

Tags: oracle

Does the elapsed_time column in the v$sql table indicate the time per query exeuction or is it a sum of all executions?

Comment: that should be pretty easy to test, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Jack: right, but it's even *easier* to ask on dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [11.2 Database Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17110/dynviews_3043.htm#REFRN30246) documentation:

> Elapsed time (in microseconds) used by this cursor for parsing,
>   executing, and fetching

Here is a demonstration:

```
SQL> SELECT sql_text, elapsed_time FROM v$sql WHERE sql_text like '%lewap %';

SQL_TEXT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ELAPSED_TIME
------------
SELECT sql_text, elapsed_time FROM v$sql WHERE sql_text like '%lewap %'
        5112


SQL> SELECT sql_text, elapsed_time FROM v$sql WHERE sql_text like '%lewap %';

SQL_TEXT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ELAPSED_TIME
------------
SELECT sql_text, elapsed_time FROM v$sql WHERE sql_text like '%lewap %'
       26332


SQL> SELECT sql_text, elapsed_time FROM v$sql WHERE sql_text like '%lewap %';

SQL_TEXT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ELAPSED_TIME
------------
SELECT sql_text, elapsed_time FROM v$sql WHERE sql_text like '%lewap %'
       65886


SQL> SELECT sql_text, elapsed_time FROM v$sql WHERE sql_text like '%lewap %';

SQL_TEXT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ELAPSED_TIME
------------
SELECT sql_text, elapsed_time FROM v$sql WHERE sql_text like '%lewap %'
      103225
```

If you need the timing for one execution you could set timing on in an SQL*Plus session, turn on tracing with TIMED_STATISTICS, or add a comment to the SQL so that there is only one execution in v$sql.